# Wordpress close menu on click off

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress installation where my 'categories' menu currently stays open when I click elsewhere on the screen. I want the menu to close if I click outside the menu.

I have added the below to my child themes functions.php:

```
function enqueue_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script("custom-script", get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/custom.js",   array("jquery"), null, true);
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "enqueue_custom_script");
```

Custom.js is a new file which contains the following:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $menuButton = $('.category-btn'); // Using class selector for the menu button
    var $menu = $('.category-dropdown'); // Using class selector for the menu

    $menuButton.on('click', function() {
        $menu.toggle();
    });

    $(document).on('click', function(event) {
        if (!$menuButton.is(event.target) && !$menu.is(event.target) &&  $menu.has(event.target).length === 0) {
            $menu.hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I dont appear to be getting any errors in the console but when looking at the page source I cannot see custom.js being called and I cant see it loading in the Network section either.

I've tried looking at both developer view and page source. I dont appear to be getting any errors in the console but when looking at the page source I cannot see custom.js being called and I cant see it loading in the Network section either.

Comment: The `script` element is an html element. Not something you put in a Javascript file.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed both the calling of the file and removed the <script> references. I've now tried a few different js methods but all either do nothing or stop the menu from opening at all.

Comment: If you can make a minimal reproducable example with the relevant html and css, that would help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've actually solved this now. For anyone else who reads this in the future the issue was that there was already an event listener for the menu button. When I then added another event listener they conflicted, causing the menu not to open when it was clicked. I added code to disable all events on the button before then adding my event and that worked.